# IP vs TCP layering principle

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

While studying layering principle in networks, I encountered those statements which I don't understand:
IP is machine-to-machine because layering principle only applies across one hop.
TCP is end-to-end because layering principle from original source to ultimate destination.
Any illustration?

Comment: Search for OSI model. You will find illustrations of the layers.

Answer (score 1):

**TCP** (Transmission Control Protocol) sits on top of **IP** (Internet Protocol), as **UDP** (User Datagram Protocol) does. The difference is that TCP has a *connection state*, whereas UDP (and IP for that matter) has not.

If you want to study **TCP/IP** you **really** should have a look at [The TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_toc.htm). It has all the details you'll ever need and beautiful and clear graphics.

[TCP/IP Protocols](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPIPProtocols.htm):

[image: TCP/IP Protocols]
<sub>(source: [tcpipguide.com](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/diagrams/tcpipprotocols.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[image: This Image illustrates both sentences.]
This Image illustrates both sentences.
**TCP** is a protocol for Transport layer.
**IP** is a protocol for Internet layer.